# How to click on a link with a span tag inside using selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am having a problem in clicking the link text given inside a span tag.

html code :

```
<div id="menu" style="width: 1752px;">
<div class="dd_menu" dd_event_id="dd_event_2">
<a class="dd_menu_menu_entry dd_menu_entry_clickable" href="javascript:void(0);" style="left: 3px; width: 111px;" dd_menu_id="0">
<a class="dd_menu_entry dd_menu_entry_clickable" href="javascript:void(0);" style="left: 114px; width: 131px;" dd_menu_id="1">
<span class="text" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">FirstMenu</span>
```

I need to click on the text 'FirstMenu' .

I have used the xpath : `.//*[@id='menu']/div/a[2]/span`

It does not seem to work. How do I fix it?

Comment: what do you mean by does not work?

Comment: It gives an error 'Unable to locate element ' with the xpath

Answer (score 1):

If your requirement is to "click on the link FirstMenu", then you should use *that* as the locator. No need to mess around with XPath.

```
    driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("FirstMenu")).click();
```

The `.partialLinkText()` locator strategy should account for any extra whitespace padding due to the extra `span` element.

Comment: That won't work because the text is inside the child `SPAN` and not the `A` tag.

Comment: @JeffC It uses inner text, and I assumed the missing closing `</a>` goes after the span,

Comment: it does have a closing tag , which i missed when i pasted the code . i am total beginner to selenium and i have just started to try it out . The website which i am testing on has more than 5 menus created similarly with the same code and different texts.

Answer (score 0):

Your xPath returns span element so you're clicking that span. To make your xpath return a link ament your query to the following:

`//*[@id='menu']/div/a[span]`

This query returns a "link" that has span element as a child.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below xpath :-

```
//span[contains(.,'FirstMenu')]
```

If it doesn't work then there may be any frame present. You need to switch it on first.

Please let me know if there is more element with name `FirstMenu` on DOM

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: You should use equals instead of `contains()` to be as specific as possible, `//span[.='FirstMenu']`

Answer (score 0):

The problem got solved by using the same xpath i specified above with the usual syntax  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='menu']/div/a[2]/span")).click(); after i gave the order by which testcases have to be executed and using @Test(priority=something) and giving some implicit waits.
 Thank you all for the suggestions.
regards,
roma

Answer (score -3):

It is not good to use xpath. If the html of the page is changed your code would stop working. Try with css selector. 
This is is simple code and you can modify it for you case:

```
var collection = driver.getelementsBy(By.cssSelector('div#menu div'))
```

It should return you collection with elements 
And after that you can iterate through collection and find the element you want to click.
Hope the answer helps you.

Comment: The `cssSelector` won't be able to find the `span` tag. Thanks

Comment: Thank you.But even after trying all the solutions here ; none of it seems to work.